# Phonegap Not working From External Server

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to make an android phonegap application which could load html file from server.
When I add refrence the web page from assets folder it works fine but when I try to open the page from server the phonegap fails.

Comment: pls check the whitelisted URL in config.xml, 
<access origin="*" />

Comment: Thanks. Now page is loading fine and also phonegap device ready is firing but Jquery Mobile css is not working.

Comment: Not sure Faraz. I can make sure only after seeing